# How to download a file with plotly-dash on a multi-page app?

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I already know about the following approach (link [here](https://docs.faculty.ai/user-guide/apps/examples/dash_file_upload_download.html)):

```
server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(server=server)


@server.route("/download/<path:path>")
def download(path):
    """Serve a file from the upload directory."""
    return send_from_directory(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, path, as_attachment=True)
```

But the problem is, when I use a multi-page-approach like suggested from Plotly (link [here](https://dash.plotly.com/urls) (below "Structuring a Multi-Page App" - `index.py`)):

```
    app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])


@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/apps/app1':
        return app1.layout
    elif pathname == '/apps/app2':
        return app2.layout
    else:
        return '404'
```

I cannot use `server.route` because it will be caught by the `callback` shown above.

What is the best way to still make files downloadable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have solved it now.

In the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/location) it says:

> The `dcc.Location` component represents the location or address bar in your web browser.

So I used an html.A element with the download option. As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), `download`

> Prompts the user to save the linked URL instead of navigating to it.

This means when the user clicks on the link, it doesn't change the address bar. Hence, the `callback` from the `display_page(pathname)` isn't called and the link is directed to the `download(path)`-method via the `@server.route` statement.

Comment: Could you share your solution?

Comment: Can you please share your code ? You shared breadcrumbs. If I figure it out I will post the solution below.

Comment: Hi, im not at the company anymore and therefore dont have the code anymore. But I think I used it like `html.A(download='filename.txt')`

Comment: Thank you for the response, one more question, do you remember where your `/download` directory was located ? was it inside `apps` or was it in your root directory. No matter what I try to do the @server.route always redirects to apps/download. and if I put `download` inside `apps/` then it routs to `apps/apps/download`. It's like playing cat and mouse with a multi-page app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
Note that the directory stage is where my temporary download files are stored
First this is what my directory tree looks like:

```
   root
    |
    |---apps
    |     └── main.py
    |---assets
    |---layouts
    |     |--layout.py
    |     └── error.py
    |---stage 
    |---app.py
    |---functions.py   
    └── index.py
```

This is what my **index.py** looks like

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

from app import app
from apps import main


app.layout = html.Div(
    [dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False), html.Div(id="page-content")]
)

@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"), [Input("url", "pathname")])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == "/main":
        return main.layout
    else:
        return main.error_page


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, host="llp-lnx-dt-10200", port=15021)
```

in **functions.py** I will dynamically produce a dash-table + the `html.A(...` with the link to download, the function is

```
def display_final_results(table):

    import dash_html_components as html
    import dash_core_components as dcc
    import dash_table
    import pandas as pd

    return html.Div(
        [
            html.H5("""File processed and stuff worked"""),
            dash_table.DataTable(
                id="result_table",
                data=table.iloc[:20, :].to_dict("records"),
                columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in list(table)],
            ),
            html.Hr(),
            dcc.Store(id="result_vault", data=table.to_dict()),
            html.A(id="download_link", children=html.Button(children="Download")),
        ]
    )
```

in **main.py** I call on the function `def_final_results(table)` passing in the table that I want to display in the dash-table and also the link for download.

Here's what the callback in **main.py** looks like followed by the `app.server.route()`

```
@app.callback(
    Output("download_link", "href"),
    [Input("result_vault","data"),
     Input("h5_filename", "children")]
)
def return_download_link(data, upload_filename):
    
    shutil.rmtree("stage")
    os.mkdir("stage")

    target = pd.DataFrame(data)
    download_filename = upload_filename.split(":")[1].strip() + f"""_{filestamp()}.xlsx"""
    uri = f"""stage/{download_filename}"""
    target.to_excel(
        uri, engine="xlsxwriter", index=False, header=True, sheet_name="results"
    )

    return uri

@app.server.route("/stage/<path:path>")
def serve_static(path):
    root_dir = os.getcwd()
    return flask.send_from_directory(os.path.join(root_dir, "stage"), filename=path)
```

in **main.py** the table `target` is saved into the directory `/stage` and the `uri` object which is the path to the file `/stage/filename+filestamp` is sent to object with id download_link as the `href` attribute, this is the `html.A(...` in the file **functions.py**. I returned the `href` since the `download` attribute did not work for me.

The big mistake that I made was that my **index.py** `dcc.Location` url used to be:

```
if pathname == "apps/main":
    return main.layout
```

So every time the routing would go to `https://llp-lnx-dt-10200:15021/apps/stage/filename`
rather than `https://llp-lnx-dt-10200:15021/stage/filename`.
By removing the apps from the url the problem was promptly solves.